# Wordpress Custom Page, posts not displaying

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

Hi i'm trying to create a custom page (custom-page.php) that contains some of my blog posts, but when I test the loop i'm not seeing any posts. Its only returning the name of my custom page template as the h2.

I have two posts already published but they are not showing up.

I have a front-page.php which users land on when they first come to my site and I have not changed any settings under the reading tab.

I've read over the Wordpress codex and can't find any solutions so far.

```
<?php
get_header();
?>

<div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">


<h1>BLOG INDEX PAGE 

    BLOG INDEX PAGE</h1>


    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent  Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
     <?php the_content(); ?>
    <?php endwhile; else : ?>

        <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>

    <?php endif; ?>

    </main><!-- #main -->
</div><!-- #primary -->


<?php
get_footer();
?>
```

Comment: Under which page you need to Show your custom template. Either in Landing Page or Blog Page ???

Comment: neither, It's just a page that contains a snippet of some of my posts

Comment: Hope so you have to set the page in the Admin Panel to display it right:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow this code.

```
$newsQuery = newWP_Query('post_type=post','post_status=publish');
if ( $newsQuery->have_posts() ) {
    while ($newsQuery->have_posts()) {
        $newsQuery->the_post();
        echo get_the_title();
        echo get_the_excerpt();
    }
}
```

and Your complete template will be like this.

```
<?php
get_header();
?>

<div id="primary" class="content-area">
<main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">


<h1>BLOG INDEX PAGE 

BLOG INDEX PAGE</h1>


   <?php 
    $newsQuery = new WP_Query('post_type=post','post_status=publish');
    if ( $newsQuery->have_posts() ) : while ( $newsQuery->have_posts() ) : $newsQuery->the_post(); ?>

    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent  Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
     <?php the_content(); ?>
    <?php endwhile; else : ?>

    <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>

<?php endif; ?>

</main><!-- #main -->
</div><!-- #primary -->


<?php
get_footer();
?>
```

Comment: This worked for me, thank you! now i need to find that documentation!

Answer (score 0):

Create a page named "Blog" from wp admin and then create a file in theme folder named page-blog.php and write the following code below.

```
<?php
get_header();
?>

<div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

    <h1>BLOG INDEX PAGE</h1>

    <?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type'     =>  'post',
        'post_status'   =>  'publish',
        'orderby' => 'id',
        'order' => 'desc'
    );  
    $loop = new WP_Query($args);
    if($loop->have_posts()) :
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

        <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent  Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
        <?php the_content(); ?>

    <?php endwhile; else :  ?>
    <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>


    </main><!-- #main -->
</div><!-- #primary -->


<?php
get_footer();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        <?php
            $args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'post',
                    'post_status' => 'publish',
                    'posts_per_page' => -1,
                    'offset' => 0
            );

            $the_query1 = new WP_Query( $args );

            if (count($the_query1->posts)>0) {
                while ( $the_query1->have_posts() ) : $the_query1->the_post();
                    get_template_part( 'loop-archive-template-location' );
                endwhile;


            }
        ?>
```